# Is it efficient to call a method (that returns a promise) inside a constructor

Tags: typescript, mongoose, constructor

I have a method that has a mongoose connection, so I was wondering is it efficient to call that method inside a connection?

```
constructor(database: string, dbmodel: string) {
this.database = database;
this.dbmodel = dbmodel;
this.models = model(dbmodel, new Schema({}));
this.configConnection(); 
}

private configConnection() {
connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/'+ this.database},options)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(error => logger.info(error));
}
```

At the moment the query results are returned after about 5-10 seconds, thus am not sure if the problem is with the implementation or calling the `configConnection` method inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it matters in this case, but I wouldn't do it like that. AFAIK constructor should be used only for instantiating object stuff, so I would use either a factory method to create the connection and then the object or just call `configConnection` after the constructor.

Either way - the only way to know for sure is to measure both approaches.

Comment: Thanks, I'll call the ```configConnection``` method after creating an instance. Very helpful.

Comment: Measuring this yourself would have taken less time than asking in stackoverflow and would have given you a way more definitive answer ;) (as stated in my answer)